# Remember login/passwords for Authentication popup windows in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, login, google-chrome-extensions, authentication, password-management

The Safari provides checkbox to save login and password in keychain for such forms. So, Is it any way to save login/password in Chrome?

[image]